# Hey folks, I'm new in sqlite and I got stuck on a training question

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, pivot

The database is as follows:

[image]

The output I want to get is:

[image]

My sql query is like this and the output I get is this.

```
SELECT score as "0-25" , COUNT(*) FROM Gamer WHERE (score > 0 and score<25)
UNION 
SELECT score as "26-50", COUNT(*) FROM Gamer WHERE (score > 26 and score<50)
UNION 
SELECT score as "51-75", COUNT(*) FROM Gamer WHERE (score > 51 and score<75)
UNION 
SELECT score as "76-100", COUNT(*) FROM Gamer WHERE (score > 76 and score<=100)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use conditional aggrgation. In SQLite:

```
select 
    sum(score between  0 and  25) as s_00_25,
    sum(score between 26 and  50) as s_26_50,
    sum(score between 51 and  75) as s_51_75,
    sum(score between 76 and 100) as s_76_100
from gamer
```